Magnetic Force Equation
Is there any equation where I can take a metal with a given volume/mass, with a certain amount of magnetic flux in it (in teslas) and find out how much force (in newtons) it exerts a given distance away?
Edit:
Here is a sketch of my setup.

All units are in inches. The piece on the left is what will become magnetized with a coil, I need to be able to move around the piece on the right which is about 126g. The piece on the left is a solid bracket that is 3/4" thick, and the piece on the right is a cylinder with a diameter of 0.5". I need to be able to move around that cylinder from 1.75" away. Since the cylinder is 126g, that works to about 1.24 newtons of force to overcome gravity, though I'd like to round up a bit for a margin of safety (let's say 1.4 or 1.5 newtons). I need to know what the best gauge of magnet wire is that I can wind around the bracket which will generate enough force. I'd also like to reduce the temperature increase as much as possible. I understand wire that thin would not be rated to handle the currents needed for this, but an increase of less than 20°F over 15 seconds is the target. Also the bracket is made of 4340 steel, and the cylinder is 1045 steel, which have around 95% and 98% iron composition respectively. My available power sources are 12V and 20V, and can output up to 15 amps, and are rated around 1Ah. Though this needs to run for less than a few minutes so battery life/capacity is not really a concern.

Whats the set up exactly? Do you have a piece of metal in the presence of a magnetic  field? or Do you want to know to force that a magnet of a certain shape repels or attracts another magnetic material from a distance?   Either way I recommend you to explain the problem with more precision, theres to many unknowns

@SantiOspina Ok, added more information.

I guess that the coil is wound around the first piece right? In other words the core of the coil would be the this "c" shaped piece?  And another cuestion,  if I understood correctly, you want to be able to pick the cilinder up from an horizontal surface where the magnet is 1.75 inches above it right?

@SantiOspina Yes, the coil is wrapped around the C shaped piece. However the whole setup is vertical, not horizontal. I need to grab the cylinder through a vertical surface that is 1.75" thick. The way it is oriented in the sketch is how it is oriented in real life.

Hey @Ombrezz Im curious, did my answer help you with developing your project? :D

I personally don't know how to properly create a theoretical model without the correct simplifications even less when taking into account the heat effects.
I would take an empirical aproach.
First considerations are:
i) Magnetic force is proportional to the number of times you wound your wire around the pice. So maximize force by increasing turns.
ii) For a fixed current,temperature increase is proportional to the resitance of the cable. Resistance itsef increases with wire lenght and decreases with cross sectional area (AWG gauge in oder words)
So based on this I would do the following:

Select a cable  rated for your maximum available current which is 15 Amps (14 AWG) (you can find some tables online)

Wind the conductor to the piece with as many turns as possible to increase inductance.

Find what is the minimum current to pick up the cilinder.

If you find that the minimun current is decently low, try to optimize temperature effects by replacing the cable with a thicker wire and approximately the same number of turns and observe its temperature behavior

If turns out that not even 15 amps are enough to lift the cilinder try repeating the test with a cable with less cross sectional area (AWG 15 for example) so that you can increase number of turns. And obviously monitor the temperature increase during those 15 seconds to check that everithing is fine.


